# %typemapping of a C++ Library for Python Interface

Tags: c++, python, interface, swig

I want to create a python wrapper for my C++ library. It would be cool, if there is a automatic conversion of std::vector to python lists and the other way round. 
Unfortunatly if I add this code to my Interface-file I still get errors in run-time.

```
%typemap(in) std::vector<float> value (std::vector<float> vIn) {
    int iLen = PySequence_Length($input); 
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < iLen; i++) {
        PyObject *o = PySequence_GetItem($input, i);
        if (PyNumber_Check(o)) {
            vIn.push_back((float)PyFloat_AsDouble(o) );
        }
    }
    $1 = vIn;
}
%typemap(out) std::vector<float> {
    std::vector<float> vOut = $1;
    int iLen = vOut.size();
    $result = PyList_New(iLen);
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < iLen; i++) {
        double fVal = vOut.at(i);
        PyObject *o = PyFloat_FromDouble((double) fVal);
        PyList_SetItem($result, i, o);
    }
}
```

Class header:

```
class TrainingSet {
    private:
        std::vector<std::vector<float> > m_vInputList;
        std::vector<std::vector<float> > m_vOutputList;
    public:
        void AddInput(const std::vector<float> &vIn);
    // ..
```

Python code:

```
trainSet = TrainingSet()
trainSet.AddInput([0.5, 0.5, 0.5])
```

Error:

```
File "runSOMNet.py", line 9, in <module>
trainSet.AddInput([0.5, 0.5, 0.5])
File "/home/dgrat/annetgpgpu/build/ANNet/ANPyNetCPU.py", line 674, in AddInput
def AddInput(self, *args): return _ANPyNetCPU.TrainingSet_AddInput(self, *args)
NotImplementedError: Wrong number or type of arguments for overloaded function      'TrainingSet_AddInput'.
Possible C/C++ prototypes are:
ANN::TrainingSet::AddInput(std::vector< float,std::allocator< float > > const &)
ANN::TrainingSet::AddInput(float *,unsigned int const &)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're going to define the `%typemap`s manually, you will also need a `%typemap(check)`, something like:

```
%typemap(typecheck) std::vector<float>& {
    $1 = PySequence_Check($input) ? 1 : 0;
}
```

I believe the rule of thumb is that if you define a `%typemap(in)`, you should also define a `%typemap(check)` --- otherwise, the generated code never gets to where it's put your `%typemap(in)`.

Answer (score 3):

The `std_vector.i` library in SWIG provides support for `std::vector`.

http://www.swig.org/Doc2.0/Library.html#Library_stl_cpp_library

You just need to tell SWIG about the template instantiations you want it to know about:

```
%include "std_vector.i"

namespace std {
    %template(FloatVector) vector<float>;
}
```

Note that the following Python code will work, but will incur an array copy:

```
for x in range(0, 3):
    list[x] = x
myModule.myFunction(list)
```

To do the same thing without incurring a copy, construct the list using the SWIG-generated proxy object constructor:

```
list = myModule.FloatVector()
for x in range(0, 3):
    list[x] = x
myModule.myFunction(list)
```

Comment: I already do this kind of stuff, but it is not what I want to do here. My goal is it to convert python lists into such a std::vector automatically when giving the python list as function argument. Or the other way round by catching the return value. The problem is, that the std::vector cannot get converted into a python list, without reading each value and writing it to the new list.

Comment: @user1909456 That's not possible. You can't construct a std::vector from a PyList without copying the data unless PyList were to support C++11 move semantics. And AFAICT you similarly can't construct a PyList from a std::vector without copying the data. But, if you use `std_vector.i` to wrap a function that returns a std::vector, then in Python it will return an object that _behaves like_ a Python list, without copying the data. And you can construct an std::vector wrapper object from Python, which _behaves like_ a Python list, and pass this to your wrapped function without copying the data.