# Swig: Pass a vector<float> from c++ to python

Tags: python, swig

I want to write some code in C++ which returns a vector to python. I tried the following example, but it returns the following object.

```
<Swig Object of type 'std::vector< float > *' at 0x100331f90>
```

How can I convert this to a list so that I can use it in python?

My code:

```
/* File: example.i */
%module example

%{
#define SWIG_FILE_WITH_INIT
#include "example.h"
%}

std::vector<float> Test(int n);
```

.

```
/* File: example.cpp */

#include <vector>

std::vector<float> Test(int n){

    std::vector<float> a(4);
    a[1] =  1;
    a[2] = 24234;
    return a;
}
```

.

```
/* File: example.h 
http://www.swig.org/Doc1.3/Python.html#Python_nn4
*/

#include <vector>
std::vector<float> Test(int n);
```

Comment: i didn't used python, but try adding `%include <std_vector.i>` in interface file

Comment: Thanks, I tried it, but it doesn't change anything.

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer to this problem. It was kind of hard to find the right keywords for this problems.

The solution is explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16528607/2737994).

```
%include <std_vector.i> //Takes care of vector<type>
```

What's still missing are the following three lines

```
namespace std
{
    %template(FloatVector) vector<float>;
}
```

In total my example.i now looks like this:

```
/* File: example.i */
%module example
%include "std_vector.i"

%{
#define SWIG_FILE_WITH_INIT
#include "example.h"
%}

namespace std
{
  %template(FloatVector) vector<float>;
}


std::vector<float> Test(int n);
```