# Wrap a C++ member vector as a Python OrderedDict

Tags: python, c++, vector, swig, ordereddictionary

EDITED TO BETTER EXPLAIN THE ISSUE:

I have a class similar to this:

```
#include <vector>
#include <utility>
#include <string>

class Test
{
public:
    std::vector<std::pair<std::string, std::string>> a;
    bool read(const std::string& path);
    bool write(const std::string& path);
}
```

and I want to modify the setter and the getter created by Swig for Python so that I can get/set an **ordered** dictionary.

Currently, using the following in the interface file:

```
%include "stl.i"

%template(string_pair) std::pair<std::string, std::string>;
%template(string_pair_vec) std::vector< std::pair<std::string, std::string>>;
```

I can write Python code like:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

t = Test()
d = OrderedDict(t.a)
t.a = string_pair_vec([(k,v) for k,v in d.items()])
```

But, when the OrderedDict is modified, the user has to proper manage `t.a` to reflect the changes.. so I think that it might be better to manage these operations directly in the SWIG generated code.

From my current understanding, if I was dealing with a simple `dict`, I could have done it using `typemap` (something like this: [%typemapping of a C++ Library for Python Interface](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16527174/2741329)), but `OrderedDict` is implemented in pure Python.

So my current intuition is that I have to use something like this in my interface file:

```
%pythonappend Test::a %{
   #Code to create and populate the ordered dict
%}
```

but the above signature does not work (or, better, I don't know how to identify the setter and the getter).

Does somebody have experience with something like this?

Comment: I doubt you have a std::vector which looks like that - string is not a model of allocator. Could you fix that?

Comment: Shame on me! Fixed

Answer (score 3):

In such cases I would advise against making your interface use `ordereddict`  per se, and instead make a "compatible" interface which in Python would work like this:

```
t = Test()
t.a = ordereddict(...).items()
print(ordereddict(t.a))
```

That is, rather than mapping your vector to an `ordereddict` directly, make the getter return a sequence (list or generator) of 2-tuples, and make the setter accept a sequence of 2-tuples.  This is more flexible, and lets users of the API store the values in a Python `list` if they prefer (which is much more similar to how you're storing them in C++).  And it sidesteps the issue of how to get `ordereddict` working in SWIG.

Comment: I have edited a bit my question to better clarify that I already have what you describe (by using SWIG templates).